# getting error HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL but not used `get` ever?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp, servlets

I'm a beginner and making a small registration program with database But i'm trying to run this but it's giving me some errors pls help:

```
HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

type Status report

message HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.
Apache Tomcat/8.0.5
```

And here is my `register.html` codes:

```
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="Register" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name">
    Email: <input type="text" name="email">
    Password: <input type="password" name="password">
    Country:

    <select name="userCountry">
        <option>India</option>
        <option>Pakistan</option>
        <option>Other</option>
    </select><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="register">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my `Register.java` codes:

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Register extends HttpServlet{
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException{
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

        String n=request.getParameter("name");
        String p=request.getParameter("password");
        String e=request.getParameter("email");
        String c=request.getParameter("userCountry");

        try{
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8888", "root", "1234"
            );

            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into REGISTERUSER values(?, ?, ?, ?)");

            ps.setString(1,n);
            ps.setString(2,p);
            ps.setString(3,e);
            ps.setString(4,c);

            int i=ps.executeUpdate();
            if(i>0){
                out.print("Registered successfully..");
            }

        }catch(Exception d){d.printStackTrace();}
        out.close();
    }
}
```

And here is my `Web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Register</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/register.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>register.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Add mysql connector jar to your application's lib path in your IDE.

Comment: Oh man ..sometime i feel to kick myself... becoz i forget every silly mistakes :p

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you mapped your servlet to `/register.html` and it expects POST method, because you implemented only `doPost()` method. So when you open `register.html` page, it will not open html page with the form but servlet that handles the form data.

Alternatively when you submit POST form to non-existing URL, web container will display 405 error (method not allowed) instead of 404 (not found).

To fix:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Register</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Or, alternatively, create a doGet() override that simply calls doPost().

Comment: I tried as you said but it's giving me only `BLANK WHITE PAGE` pls help :(

Comment: Now i can display the form but ... when i click to submit button, it redirects to white blank page and not showing "Registered successfully" message... neither my material is saved into database...

Comment: it's showing `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:8888`

Comment: Your code does not print anything in response if there is some problem. See application server logs for exceptions. SQL issue?

Comment: What application server do you use? You need to copy mysql jdbc driver either to libs of app server or bundle it in WEB-INF/lib directory of your web application.

Comment: thanks man..i forget to add driver connector to my IDE.. silly mistakes :p

Answer (score 3):

Override service method like this:

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse   response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
}
```

And Voila!

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue may be in the url pattern. Changing

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Register</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and

```
<form action="/Register" method="post">
```

may fix your problem

Comment: It should `<form action="/Register" method="post">`

Comment: Yep I know. Thanks for picking this up, I've updated the answer

Comment: URL /Register will work only for webapp deployed as ROOT (without context)

Comment: But there is one problem when i click submit .. it doesn't show the message `Registered succesfully` neither i can see into database that matter...

Comment: Please feel free to up-vote and mark the answer as a solution if it was the solution :)

Comment: is there any exception in the logs? Maybe the servlet is breaking for some reason

Comment: @user3631223: Check the console logs. There might occurred an Exception.

Comment: OMG! you were  right: it's showing into console `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:8888`

Comment: well you didn't... Anyway if you had to change the action in the form too the accepted answer should be updated in order to be more helpful for the other SO users