# JSP JasperException

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jsp, servlets

So I have an SQL query and I want to select data from a database but I am getting a strange exception I do know less about it. Note that I am new to JSPs.

I have this file called selectform.jsp where I want to take data from a database and display it in a table:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
<%@ page extends="proiect.Database"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Select</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        String query = "SELECT * FROM arhiva ORDER BY id";
        try {
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    %>

    <table border=1>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nume</th>
                <th>Prenume</th>
            </tr>
            <%
                while (rs.next()) {
            %>
            <tr>
                <td><%=rs.getString("id")%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString("nume")%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString("prenume")%></td>
            </tr>
            <%
                }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            %>

        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Note that I am taking stuff from a Database.java file in the proiect package with the following line "<%@ page extends="proiect.Database"%>".
That file looks like:

```
package proiect;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.UnavailableException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.jsp.HttpJspPage;

public abstract class Database extends HttpServlet implements HttpJspPage {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected Connection con;
    protected String driver = "org.postgresql.Driver";
    protected String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5200/postgres";
    protected String user = "postgres";
    protected String pass = "test";
    Connection connection = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    String query = null;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new UnavailableException(e.getMessage());
        }

        jspInit();
    }

}
```

And when I try to run that selectform.jsp, I get the following stacktrace:

```
Jan 12, 2015 11:58:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Project] threw exception [Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [20] in the generated java file: [E:\Eclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\Project\org\apache\jsp\selectform_jsp.java]
The type selectform_jsp must implement the inherited abstract method JspPage.jspInit()

An error occurred at line: [20] in the generated java file: [E:\Eclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\Project\org\apache\jsp\selectform_jsp.java]
The type selectform_jsp must implement the inherited abstract method JspPage.jspDestroy()

Stacktrace:] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [20] in the generated java file: [E:\Eclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\Project\org\apache\jsp\selectform_jsp.java]
The type selectform_jsp must implement the inherited abstract method JspPage.jspInit()

An error occurred at line: [20] in the generated java file: [E:\Eclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\Project\org\apache\jsp\selectform_jsp.java]
The type selectform_jsp must implement the inherited abstract method JspPage.jspDestroy()

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:485)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:379)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

selectform_jsp.java:

```
/*
 * Generated by the Jasper component of Apache Tomcat
 * Version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.56
 * Generated at: 2015-01-12 09:58:28 UTC
 * Note: The last modified time of this file was set to
 *       the last modified time of the source file after
 *       generation to assist with modification tracking.
 */
package org.apache.jsp;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.jsp.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.*;

public final class selectform_jsp extends proiect.Database
    implements org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspSourceDependent {

  private static final javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory _jspxFactory =
          javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory.getDefaultFactory();

  private static java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Long> _jspx_dependants;

  private javax.el.ExpressionFactory _el_expressionfactory;
  private org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager _jsp_instancemanager;

  public java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Long> getDependants() {
    return _jspx_dependants;
  }

  public void _jspInit() {
    _el_expressionfactory = _jspxFactory.getJspApplicationContext(getServletConfig().getServletContext()).getExpressionFactory();
    _jsp_instancemanager = org.apache.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(getServletConfig());
  }

  public void _jspDestroy() {
  }

  public void _jspService(final javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, final javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response)
        throws java.io.IOException, javax.servlet.ServletException {

    final javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext pageContext;
    javax.servlet.http.HttpSession session = null;
    final javax.servlet.ServletContext application;
    final javax.servlet.ServletConfig config;
    javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter out = null;
    final java.lang.Object page = this;
    javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter _jspx_out = null;
    javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext _jspx_page_context = null;


    try {
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      pageContext = _jspxFactory.getPageContext(this, request, response,
                null, true, 8192, true);
      _jspx_page_context = pageContext;
      application = pageContext.getServletContext();
      config = pageContext.getServletConfig();
      session = pageContext.getSession();
      out = pageContext.getOut();
      _jspx_out = out;

      out.write("\r\n");
      out.write("\r\n");
      out.write("\r\n");
      out.write("\r\n");
      out.write("\r\n");
      out.write("<html>\r\n");
      out.write("<head>\r\n");
      out.write("<title>Select</title>\r\n");
      out.write("</head>\r\n");
      out.write("<body>\r\n");
      out.write("\t");

        String query = "SELECT * FROM arhiva ORDER BY id";
        try {
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

      out.write("\r\n");
      out.write("\r\n");
      out.write("\t<table border=1>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t<tbody>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t\t<tr>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t\t\t<th>ID</th>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t\t\t<th>Nume</th>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t\t\t<th>Prenume</th>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t\t</tr>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t\t");

                while (rs.next()) {

      out.write("\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t\t<tr>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t\t\t<td>");
      out.print(rs.getString("id"));
      out.write("</td>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t\t\t<td>");
      out.print(rs.getString("nume"));
      out.write("</td>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t\t\t<td>");
      out.print(rs.getString("prenume"));
      out.write("</td>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t\t</tr>\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t\t");

                }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

      out.write("\r\n");
      out.write("\r\n");
      out.write("\t\t</tbody>\r\n");
      out.write("\t</table>\r\n");
      out.write("\r\n");
      out.write("</body>\r\n");
      out.write("</html>");
    } catch (java.lang.Throwable t) {
      if (!(t instanceof javax.servlet.jsp.SkipPageException)){
        out = _jspx_out;
        if (out != null && out.getBufferSize() != 0)
          try {
            if (response.isCommitted()) {
              out.flush();
            } else {
              out.clearBuffer();
            }
          } catch (java.io.IOException e) {}
        if (_jspx_page_context != null) _jspx_page_context.handlePageException(t);
        else throw new ServletException(t);
      }
    } finally {
      _jspxFactory.releasePageContext(_jspx_page_context);
    }
  }
}
```

Where is the issue? I don't understand why I'm getting an error. Thank you in advance, SO!

Comment: @Sharp edge this ist the generated java file from `select_form.jsp`. A jsp file is a "newer" form of java servlets.

Comment: My selectform.jsp is inside ...\Project\WebContent.

Comment: @AlexandruMitu the `jsp` file is converted into a `servlet` resulting in a `.java file` of that jsp page..

Comment: you have to check generated java files form jsp and then find line no `[20]` in it.

Comment: @atishshimpi I posted that generated file.

Comment: which is line no 20 in your generated file

Comment: @atishshimpi "public final class selectform_jsp extends proiect.Database"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here

```
public abstract class Database extends HttpServlet implements HttpJspPage
```

You are implementing the HttpJspPage interface. All methods in an interface is public abstract in nature and need to over-rided by the implementing class. since the two methods init() and destroy() from HttpJspPage is not over-rided you are getting an exception. You can get rid of the error my giving these methods an implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Issue with extending class `<%@ page extends="proiect.Database"%>` in you JSP.

> public abstract class Database extends HttpServlet implements
>   HttpJspPage

Don't implements `HttpJspPage` in `Database` Servlet.

Comment: HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Comment: is this method came while form submission, check your `<form>` method and servlet method. refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624442/getting-error-http-status-405-http-method-get-is-not-supported-by-this-url-but

Comment: But why you declared your servlet as `abstract` it confusing me.