# How to send parameter from html form to servlet in url on button click?

Tags: java, html, servlets

Hey I am trying to send a Parameter from html form to servlet via URL on button click.
I am getting this error message

> HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Comment: yes you get the message because "HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL". Show us please some code...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624442/getting-error-http-status-405-http-method-get-is-not-supported-by-this-url-but

Comment: here is the code
<input type="button" value="Reject" class="button" onclick="location.href='UserController?id=cancelProducts'"/>

Comment: I want to send id= cancelProducts to servlet but getting error

Comment: @Ak.Jain how you are sending the parameter?Show the code

Answer (score 2):

To complete a GET request using servlets you must override the doGet method of the class you have extended from HttpServlet.

The http methods of the HttpServlet class are not abstract however, so failing to override them will not generate an error, it will just mean that the service method defaults back to the HttpServlet methods, and return the html that you received.

Comment: yes i didn't override doGet method in my servlet

Comment: Sorry Muhammed.  How would you like me to rectify this?  Should I delete the answer or just edit?